# Priority queue with Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator, priority-queue

I am using priority queue to store elements of Identity HashMap (so as to keep duplicate keys also). I want to add elements of IdentityHashMap in Priority Queue based on keys in descending order and print their indexes (starting from 1). But it is not giving correct output.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        IdentityHashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new IdentityHashMap<>();
        PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> p = new PriorityQueue<>(new my_Comparator());
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[size];
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            a[index] = sc.nextInt();
            hm.put(a[index], index + 1);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> temp : hm.entrySet()) {
            p.add(temp);
        }
        while (p.size() != 0) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> temp = p.poll();
            System.out.print(temp.getValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class my_Comparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        Integer i1 = o1.getKey();
        Integer i2 = o2.getKey();
        if (i1.equals(i2)) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
        return i2.compareTo(i1);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
8
19 1 8 25 20 12 4 25
```

The correct output would be this:

```
8 4 5 1 6 3 7 2
```

*These are the indices of elements after sorting in priority queue according to descending order.*

My code's output is:

```
8 5 1 6 3 7 2
```

Comment: Please look up and try to follow Java code formatting rules. By following these rules, others will more easily be able to read and understand your code, and then be able to help you. If you are using most IDE's they can help you format your code correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming because you are trying to use duplicate values in the input.

```
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
          a[index] = sc.nextInt();
          hm.put(a[index], index + 1);
      }
```

When 25 is entered for the first time, it saves the value of 25 and the  one-index at which it is entered.
When 25 is entered again at the end, it updates the value of index.HashMap.put basically updates the value if key is already present.
Therefore, in the original hashMap , only 7 entries were present.

To resolve your issue ,
Use indices as key and the value present as value of the hashMap.
Then it will store both the entries when 25 is entered.
This is the working code which gives the desired output

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
public static void main (String[] args) {

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
IdentityHashMap<Integer,Integer> hm=new IdentityHashMap<>();
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>p=new PriorityQueue<>(new myComparator());
    int size=sc.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[size];
for(int index=0;index<size;index++)
{
    a[index]=sc.nextInt();
    hm.put(index+1,a[index]);
}
//System.out.println(hm);
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> temp:hm.entrySet())
{
    p.add(temp);
}
while(p.size()!=0)
{Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>temp=p.poll();
    System.out.print(  temp.getKey() + " ") ;

}
System.out.println();
}       


}
class myComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>
{
    
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>o1,Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> o2)
    {
    Integer i1 =o1.getValue();
    Integer i2 =o2.getValue();
    if(i1.equals(i2))
    {
         return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
      
    }
   
     return i2.compareTo(i1);
       
    }
   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I have a small doubt that I am using IdentityHashMap here which has capability of holding duplicate keys then why it is not storing duplicate keys.?

Comment: when you are inserting the values in the hashmap, 
use hm.put(new Integer(a[index],index+1) ; 
This will basically create a new key instead of retrieving the key from the hashmap.

Comment: if you do the change suggested in comment in your code, your code will work fine.